# Python C API Getting the whole exception as string

Tags: python, c

I am following the documentation "Embedding Python in Another Application". I would like to get the exception of;

```
PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                       "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
```

into a string variable. Any ideas on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Yes for example if the input was "sdfsadf" there is an exception NameError: name 'sdfsadf' is not defined